# How do I populate a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to Rails and I am currently trying to wrap my head around the model/db aspect of the framework. Albeit, I am having some trouble with understanding the connections between models, the database schema, and the views/controller.

For example, lets say that I have an Articles model and the Articles model has_many authors. How do I go about populating the Articles model with actual Articles/content and the Authors model with an array of corresponding Authors?

In other words: If I were to have

```
articles = Articles.search(params[:search])
```

in my controller how would the Articles object know to search the actual Articles/content that I have written in the view? I am having trouble understanding that connection.

I hope this makes sense.

Any insights would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Hey Tony, you have a few different questions there. I would recommend going through a tutorial (such as this one http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) that will help you understand how everything comes together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of questions hidden in your question, so here are some answers:

- `Article` is a class (note, it is singular), that provides class methods to operate on Article data. These class methods could be: `Article.new`, `Article.find` (the methods are defined by [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)). You also can define your own class methods, such as Article.search, which probably gives you an array of Article instances: `articles`.
- `articles` is only visible in the local scope of your controller action. If you use `@articles` you promote the variable to become an instance variable, that can then be used for rendering of the view. (A view renderer can access controller instance variables)
- In order to store data from a model in the database, you use the methods that an `Article` instance inherits from ActiveRecord, such as `article.save`
- The whole process of bringing data from a view into the database therefore is: `@article = Article.new' defines an empty model that can be loaded from a form in a view. If the form is submitted,`@article = Article.create(params[:article])`would save the data into the database. And`@articles = Article.search(params[:search])` would then give you back an array with objects, that could be rendered in the view.

Some references:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html